# UltiSnips comment variable

Tags: autocompletion, plugin-ultisnips

VSCode have the following variables that are quite helpful when creating snippets:

1. `BLOCK_COMMENT_START` Example output: in PHP `/*` or in HTML `<!--`
2. `BLOCK_COMMENT_END` Example output: in PHP `*/` or in HTML `-->`
3. `LINE_COMMENT` Example output: in PHP `//`

I searched the documentation of UltiSnips and I have not found an equivalent variables that can be used in code interpolation. Does UltiSnips

Concept:

```
snippet todo "creates a todo comment
`!p snip.rv = snip.LINE_COMMENT`TODO: $1
endsnippet
```

[More background about this here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/55946).

Comment: Per the page you linked you can type `todo` as a snippet in various file types and you'll get language-appropriate block comments. Couldn't you just copy the associated snippet(s) and remove the "todo" part from the emitted text? Or perhaps I'm not understanding what you require...

Comment: You could use `&l:commentstring`, which is a vimscript variable for the option of the same name. Check how it's formatted though.

Comment: @BLayer What do you mean? The page that I've linked is about VSCode not UltiSnips.

Comment: But the functionality I'm referring to is implemented in Ultisnips, too (you might need the compatible snippet collection vim-snippets, actually).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Overview

Ultisnips supports vimscript interpolation. To illustrate, the todo snippet for a block comment will have following structure:

```
snippet todob "todo with block comment" b
`!v {BLOCK_COMMENT_START}`TODO: $1`!v {BLOCK_COMMENT_END}`
endsnippet
```

where `{BLOCK_COMMENT_START}` and `{BLOCK_COMMENT_END}` are vimscript expressions, that we have to construct. The usage of `` `!v ` `` tells Ultisnips that we are doing a vimscript interpolation. (This is akin to `` `!p ` `` for python interpolation.)

The variables in vim would be `&l:commentstring` and `&l:comments`. We will have to extract the relevant strings from them.

### Extract Block Comment Markers

As Ben mentioned in the comments, we can access the comment variables with `&l:commentstring`. This vim variable is filetype dependent, from which we can extract the start and end of block comments. From `:h 'commentstring'`, it is of the form

```
"{BLOCK_COMMENT_START}%s{BLOCK_COMMENT_END}"
```

Therefore, we can use vimscript to extract the start and end block comment markers:

```
function GetBlockCommentMarks()
  return split(&l:commentstring, '%s')
endfunction
```

This function returns a list of the form `["{BLOCK_COMMENT_START}","{BLOCK_COMMENT_END}"]`.

### Snippet for Block Comments

Now, we replace `BLOCK_COMMENT_*` with a call to our newly written function, to get the following snippet for block comments:

```
snippet todob "todo with block comment" b
`!v GetBlockCommentMarks()[0]`TODO: $1`!v GetBlockCommentMarks()[1]`
endsnippet
```

### Extract Line Comment Marker

Things are more involved for line comments. Depending on the language or filetype, it can be found in `&l:commentstring` or `&l:comments`, or both.

- If the filetype only has line comments, the line comment marker may be found in &l:commentstring, in the form `"{LINE_COMMENT} %s"`
- Otherwise, it can be found in `&l:comments`

Like `&l:commentstring`, `&l:comments` is also filetype dependent. However, unlike `&l:commentstring`, it is a comma-separated list of parts of the form `{flag}:{string}`. It is more involved (and one can refer to `:h 'comments'` and `:h format-comments` for details), but for our purposes, what is relevant here is the `{string}` without any `{flag}`s.

One can use a regex to extract this `{string}`, as the following function illustrates:

```
function GetCommentMarker()
  if len(split(&l:commentstring, '%s')) == 1
    " if 'commentstring' xx%sxx contains no end part
    return split(&l:commentstring, '%s')[0]
  elseif match(&l:comments, '\v(,|^):[^,:]*(,|$)')
    " if 'comments' contains ',:xxx,'
    return matchstr(&l:comments, '\v(,|^):\zs[^,:]*\ze(,|$)')
  else
    echoerr "unable to find line comment marker."
  endif
endfunction
```

The above function first checks if `&l:commentstring` is of the appropriate form, and if so, extracts the relevant comment string. Otherwise it extracts the string from `&l:comments`.

### Snippet for Line Comments

Finally, we call this function from inside our snippet, using vim interpolation once again:

```
snippet todoc "todo with line comment" b
`!v GetCommentMarker()`TODO: $1
endsnippet
```

### Edit: Block Comment Markers Revisited

There are some filetypes (such as java) where `&l:commentstring` stores the marker for a line comment, instead of block comments. In that case, one has to access the block comment markers via `&l:comments`.

Of relevance are the strings associated with the `s` and `e` flags, which specify the **s**tart and **e**nd of a block comment (Technically, the `s`,`m`,`e` flags come together, but the **m**iddle part can be ignored here).

As before, one can use a regex to extract the relevant strings, which we will add to the previously written function `GetBlockCommentMarks`. While we're at it, lets add an additional check to `&l:commentstring`.

```
function GetBlockCommentMarks()
  if len(split(&l:commentstring, '%s')) == 2
    " if 'commentstring' xx%sxx contains start and end part
    return split(&l:commentstring, '%s')
  endif

  let three_comment = matchstr(&l:comments, '\v(,|^)\zss[^O]{-}:.{-},m.{-}:.{-},e.{-}:.{-}\ze(,|$)')
  if three_comment != ""
    " if 'comments' contains s:xx,m:xx,e:xx
    let start_comment = matchstr(three_comment, '\v^s.{-}:\zs.{-}\ze,')
    let end_comment   = matchstr(three_comment, '\v,e.{-}:\zs.{-}\ze$')
    return [start_comment, end_comment]
  endif
  echoerr "unable to find block comment markers."
endfunction
```

The regex in the first `matchstr()` tries to pull `s:xx,m:xx,e:xx` from `l&:comments`; the next two `matchstr()`s extract the start and end comment markers. (The use of `[^O]` is an ad-hoc addition, so that it works with the java filetype)

### Wrapping up

Here's the full code

```
" vim
function GetCommentMarker()
  if len(split(&l:commentstring, '%s')) == 1
    " if 'commentstring' xx%sxx contains no end part
    return split(&l:commentstring, '%s')[0]
  elseif match(&l:comments, '\v(,|^):[^,:]*(,|$)')
    " if 'comments' contains ',:xxx,'
    return matchstr(&l:comments, '\v(,|^):\zs[^,:]*\ze(,|$)')
  else
    echoerr "unable to find line comment marker."
  endif
endfunction

function GetBlockCommentMarks()
  if len(split(&l:commentstring, '%s')) == 2
    " if 'commentstring' xx%sxx contains start and end part
    return split(&l:commentstring, '%s')
  endif

  let three_comment = matchstr(&l:comments, '\v(,|^)\zss[^O]{-}:.{-},m.{-}:.{-},e.{-}:.{-}\ze(,|$)')
  if three_comment != ""
    " if 'comments' contains s:xx,m:xx,e:xx
    let start_comment = matchstr(three_comment, '\v^s.{-}:\zs.{-}\ze,')
    let end_comment   = matchstr(three_comment, '\v,e.{-}:\zs.{-}\ze$')
    return [start_comment, end_comment]
  endif
  echoerr "unable to find block comment markers."
endfunction
```

```
# snippets
snippet todoc "todo with line comment" b
`!v GetCommentMarker()`TODO: $1
endsnippet

snippet todob "todo with block comment" b
`!v GetBlockCommentMarks()[0]`TODO: $1`!v GetBlockCommentMarks()[1]`
endsnippet
```

Happy vimming!

Comment: Thank you! Great answer. It worked for C++, but not in Java and python: `vim.error: Vim:E684: list index out of range: `. So, I suppose vim returns an array of 1 element since python does not have a `BLOCK_END`. But Java should return a 2-element array.

Comment: Hi, sorry for my late reply. I believe you are referring to block comments... Yes, python gives an error since it has no `BLOCK_COMMENT_END`. java is an interesting case, in that `&l:commentstring` contains `LINE_COMMENT`, instead of `BLOCK_COMMENT_*`. So, one has to extract `BLOCK_COMMENT_*` from `&l:comments`. See my edit

Comment: Nice. It works for Java, but unfortunately not python nor LaTeX. I still don't know much about vimscript to make a `matchstr` for python.

Comment: @AvidSeeker Does it work if you replace the two lines containing `echoerr "unable to find..."` with `return ""`?

Comment: Not exactly. This just suppresses the error, and instead of inserting the comment character it leaves it empty. I've just tried it on Python and LaTeX file types.

Comment: Hm, I tried it and it works for me. `todoc` gives me `# TODO:` and `% TODO:` when 'filetype' is set to python and tex respectively.

Comment: Or are you talking about block comments? Python and tex do not use block comments, so `todob` wouldn't make any sense here...

Comment: I have a multiline comment snippet in `all.snippets`. It'd be convenient to code the snippet such that if the language doesn't support block comments, it appends an inline comment symbol in each line of the snippets. This almost mimics the behavior of `gc` in vim if you have a comment plugin. + For python, it's convenient to have `'''` as a block comment start and end.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand better what you are trying to achieve. However, I think that warrants a new question. For now, feel free to modify my answer to meet your needs. I hope it has answered your original question :)